# How to send files discovered by glob to (default) printer

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to write a program that will take all the files with a specified extension in a directory and print them consecutively.  It would be great if they could be printed more than once each time but one step at a time for now.

I plan to keep the .py file in the directory that I will be running the glob on to avoid directory placeholder headaches...

I have tried the following:

```
import os
import glob

os.startfile((glob.glob('*.docx*')), "print")
```

This gives me the following message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cmobley\Desktop\HI\print all in folder.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.startfile((glob.glob('*.docx*')), "print")
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

I understand there is some sort of missing link here I just can't put my finger on it.  I have also tried other approaches with no success.  I have successfully printed individual documents before using the os.startfile with the print argument.  I am very much so a beginner so please go easy on me!  I am using python 3.5 so my glob module is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glob.glob returns a list of strings, you can't os.startfile a list, you have to do it for each string in the list. That explains `TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly`

```
import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob('*.docx*'):
    os.startfile(filename, "print")
```

Multiple prints:

```
import glob
import os

numPrints = 10

for filename in glob.glob('*.txt*'):
    for i in range(numPrints):
        print("Printing file", filename, "copy", i+1)
        os.startfile(filename, "print")
```

Comment: That is very helpful.  I tried something like that but must have over-complicated it.  Any thoughts on getting each file to print say for example 10 times before moving on to the next file the glob finds?  I need some direction!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding that correctly, you want to print every single file ten times?

Comment: You just have to loop 10 times for each file, updated my answer